# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm update React to 16.3.0 and my app crashed with `Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles'`.
I try write this command to console: `npm install --save-dev react-scripts`, but it is not help, I else try delete node modules from project and reinstall it with `npm i` but without any  result.

Dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "radium": "^0.19.4",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you're using "create-react-app"

I would recommend you delete `package-lock.json` then run `npm install`

> In most cases bumping the react-scripts version in package.json and
>   running npm install in this folder should be enough.

```
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@1.1.4
```

[create-react-app update](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#updating-to-new-releases)

Comment: I had working project and changed react version to 16.3 in package.json, then running npm i

Comment: I have only this warning
`npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

Comment: `npm install ajv`

Comment: It is not help.

Comment: What about my updated answer, advising you to delete `package-lock.json`

Comment: Yes____________